# Include в echo или что-то подобное

Tags: php

Ситуация такая:

Есть сайт, а у сайта есть файл php с переменными.
И есть обработчик, который после заполнения 1 шага формы обрабатывает этот шаг и с помощью `echo ''` отображает второй шаг.

Можно как-то в это `echo` заинклюдить файл с переменными, чтобы использовать список тех переменных в `echo '.$kak_to_tak.'`?

Comment: Если в файле есть оператор `return $kak_to_tak;`, то можно делать так `echo include'file.php';`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно 
Файл **main.php**

```
<?php
include "variable.php";

echo $kak_to_tak;
```

Файл **variable.php**

```
<?php
$kak_to_tak = "Hello world!";
```

Результат: **Hello world!**